No internet connection when scheduled task starts or when Sql server agent job starts
I've a task that runs daily which is failing because it starts without internet connection.
I tried to tick wait for network but it doesn't work either.
I tried to register the task with System and with my personal Account, logged in or not, neither works.
I thought maybe it needs a few seconds before the connection is established after login and I put a 10 second wait in the program but I get the same error.
I then tried moved the task to a Sql server agent job as it was related to another job anyways but I have the exact same issue.
The task works fine when I log in and execute it manually.
This is a Windows 10 Server, What can I do to resolve this issue?

Any chance your script is referencing a mapped drive letter? Can you post the error output?

Nope, it's a network related error, the request is sent but times out

Could you try waiting for a ping to succeed before starting your program? Try this RunProgramWhenNetworkAvailable.ps1. If this doesn't work then you know it's not really a network not being available issue.

Nope, I'm waiting a full minute now and same issue: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I suspect this is mainly a firewall issue

The issue was caused by the corporation firewall filtering traffic when not logged in
